# Angular 6 Library - Import module issue

Tags: angular, ng-build

I am building a library with 3 components, say A,B,C and generating a tgz file out of it. i am consuming this library in another angular application by doing npm install. Components A and B from the library work perfectly fine in the new application as it is straight forward and doesnt have any services or class. However component C has a service and when i am trying to use this in my application, I am getting an error. I tried giving the full path to the service in the import statement like : 
`import { ABClibservice } from 'ABClib/lib/ABClib/ABClib.service';`

When i run this project its showing an error like :

`ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve'`

Comment: what happens if you use a relative path?

Comment: i tried giving relative path but it does not work! i have given the path as : ` import { ABCservice } from '../../node_modules/ABClib/lib/abclibt/abc.service' `; 
 I am still getting module not found error. However there is a abc.service.d.ts file in that path. i dont know if that is causing any issue.

Comment: oh, it's in node_modules? You usually need an `index.d.ts` that's exporting each type in the module from a single location in order to satisfy `moduleResolution`: `node`'s bundling resolution. That's going to be where your issue is; I'd post your bundled output instead and/or look at other bundled packages and how they're exporting types

Comment: I am exporting all the components in my library from a public_api.ts folder. Are you talking about that? or do i need to make any modifications in my new application to use my library? When i say "npm i abc.tgz" , it gets copied to node_modules as usual and i am trying to use that path. Am i going wrong here? What is the right way to import a libarry apart from importing it in app.module.ts?

Comment: Again, it's very hard to say without seeing more of your code. The error itself is in `app.component.ts`, not the module, so I'd assume you're not having a problem including it in your `app.module.ts`...it's the compiler trying to find the type token for the service itself that's throwing an error. If the type for the service is being exported from a top-level module file like a `public_api.d.ts`, you should import it from there and not from the declaration file.